# Netbeans and Zend-Framework

Tags: php, apache, zend-form

I have just started using the Zend-Framework. On advice of a friend I use NetBeans for PHP development with Zend. I have installed NetBeans and referenced the Zend-Framework under Tools>Options>PHP>Zend, registered it since I am using a version newer then 1.10.

Under PHP>General I have inluded the Zend-library path as a Global-Include-Path.

Since I've read that the beginners tutorial provided on the website (http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-project.html) has some errors and since it does not use NetBeans I started with this video tutorial: http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/zend-framework-screencast.html

Creating the project as a Zend-Framework Project worked just fine, all default folders and files are created. However, when I run the project with this defauilt setup the browser should diplay the index.php provided by the Framework under localhost/quickstart, instead of that it just displays a listing of the files of directories:

**Index of /quickstart**

- Parent Directory
- .zfproject.xml
- application/
- docs/
- library/
- nbproject/
- public/
- tests/

I suppose there is something wrong with the configuration of the apache server but the video screencast did not mention any needed configuration when using netbeans.

I am using xampp and one of the things that might be the problem is the *httpd.conf* file as described in the tutorial (http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-project.html) since no *NameVirtualHost*-propperty is defined there and no *VirtualHost* configured. However I didn't want to change the *httpd.conf* without knowing if that is the problem.

Also adding a line "127.0.0.1 quickstart.local" to the *hosts* file turned out to be impossible under Windows 7, so in case this is actually neccesary, I would apreciate any help.

Thanks,

Lukas

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the DocumentRoot in the apache httpd-vhost.conf to the public folder?

All you should need to do is add public to the end of your current document root...

Also to change the vhosts file in windows 7 you need to find notepad in the start menu -> all programs -> accessories

Right click and run as Administrator

File -> open -> C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

Now add your records and save.

Opening as Administrator allows the save to attually save the changes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer however, I'm not entirely sure what to do. I have a "httpd-vhosts.conf"-file in xampp, but everything in it is commented out with "#".

Should I uncomment "NameVirtualHost *:80" and add

    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName quickstart.local
        DocumentRoot C:\xampp\htdocs\quickstart
     
        SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
     
        <Directory C:\xampp\htdocs\quickstart\public>
            DirectoryIndex index.php
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>

Comment: well, now localhost/quickstart can not be found but localhost itself shows the folder structure thet previously was found under localhost/quickstart

Interesting, but still not working as intended.

Comment: If your apache instance isn't using the vhosts config then you are just using one host, meaning the DocumentRoot will be located in the httpd.conf rather than the httpd-vhosts.conf.

Also remember to restart the apache service after changing the config files.

Answer (score 0):

Ironically, I just went through all of this yesterday.  First, what happens when you type:  localhost/quickstart/public, into your browser instead of: localhost/quickstart ?  The controller is accessed via the index action and .htaccess file inside that directory.

Second, in regards to editing the hosts file... I have windows 7 as well, and all i did to find it was type "system32" in the Search Programs and files, then follow the path to the hosts file.  I was able to edit it using notepad and it worked great!

there are two steps to configuring the vhost after that.  You will need to uncomment a line in the httpd.conf file under the apache folder, remove the # from httpd.conf:

```
#Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Then go to the extras folder and add the following to the bottom of your httpd-vhosts.conf file like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/path_to_local_webroot/quickstart.com/public"
    ServerName quickstart.com
    ServerAlias quickstart.com
    ErrorLog "logs/quickstart.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/quickstart.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

For your hosts file, just add one line to the bottom:

```
127.0.0.1 quickstart.com
```

Then restart your server and you should be good to go.